# How can I get the Wordpress 'Preview' link to open in the same window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I asked [How can I make the “Preview Post” button save and preview in the same window?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35517/how-can-i-make-the-preview-post-button-save-and-preview-in-the-same-window) on the Wordpress Stack Exchange, but this may be a better question for Stack Overflow as it is more directly related to coding.

Wordpress has a box that allows you to save, preview, and publish your blog posting:

[image: Picture.png]

The "Preview" button is actually a link styled as a button:

```
<a tabindex="4" id="post-preview" target="wp-preview"
href="/?p=67&amp;preview=true" class="preview button">Preview</a>
```

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to get that link to open in the current window. Notice the `target="wp-preview"` part. I'm trying to get rid of that part, but I think there may be another function bound to that element because I really can't get it to open in current tab / window, even after unbinding it and removing the `target` attribute.

I'm running the following code as part of a plugin (you can see more info on how to run this as a plugin below), but it is also possible to copy and paste this into Chrome or Firefox's console to test this out yourself without even modifying Wordpress. Please note that when testing you'll need to use `jQuery` instead of `$` in your own functions as Wordpress uses the `noconflict` method, however the code below is working fine as is.

```
//select the node and cache the selection into a variable
var $node = jQuery('a.preview'); 

//add a 1px dotted outline to show we have the right element
$node.css('outline','1px dotted red'); 

//show current target
console.log($node.prop('target')); 
//show if anything is bound - nothing is for me ('undefined')
console.log($node.data('events')); 

//remove anything bound to it
$node.unbind(); 
//set target to _self (current window), just in case
$node.prop('target','_self'); 
//the remove the target attribute all together
$node.removeAttr('target'); 

//clone the node
var $clone = $node.clone(); 
//change the text to new
$clone.text('new'); 
//remove target from clone
$clone.removeAttr('target'); 
//unbind the clone
$clone.unbind(); 
//insert the clone after the original node
$node.after($clone); 

//show current target - now shows undefined for me
console.log($node.prop('target'));
//show if anything is bound - still 'undefined'
console.log($node.data('events'));
```

This is how you would work the code into a theme or plugin:

```
// set up an action to set a function to run in the wp admin_footer
add_action('admin_footer','my_admin_footer_script',9999);
```

Here is the function that adds the javascript:

```
//this function can then be used to add javascript code to the footer

function my_admin_footer_script(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
     (above js code here)
    });
    </script>


    <?php
}
```

This is the result I end up with. If I click the "test" link it will open in the same window. If I click the Preview link it still opens in a new tab.

[image: Picture.png]

ps: I'm using the method from [Things you may not know about jQuery](https://j11y.io/javascript/things-you-may-not-know-about-jquery/) to check for bound events, and I didn't find anything bound, and I believe Wordpress primarily uses jQuery so I don't think this would be bound with another event handler.

Comment: If they're using event delegation you won't be able to use the data('events') trick. I also think that newer versions of jQuery might have gotten rid of that anyway.

Comment: But unbind should still work as it's a native function, right? Per the jQuery documentation: `$('#foo').unbind(); // This version removes the handlers regardless of type.`

Comment: Unbind won't work if they used delegate, since there's not actually an event bound to that element.

The way delegate works is that they listen to events higher up in the DOM, and then interrogate the event object to see where it came from. If you can figure out which element the event is bound to, you can use undelegate.

Anyway, this is purely conjecture on my part. I don't know for sure that they're even using delegate.

Comment: If you have any tips for finding delegated events in jQuery please post it as an answer :) I will look up `undelegate` but perhaps I could loop through with `.parent()` and run `undelegate` to test.

Comment: If you use Chrome inspector you and expand Event Listeners you will see that there are three bound for the click event. One for the preview button, one for the div containing it and one for the document. Not sure which one is responsible for the window opening.

Comment: @mrtsherman - i'm seeing three but not for the preview button. what am i missing? http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/3918/picture3df.png

Comment: Not that I think it matters anymore as you have an answer - but this is what I see when I inspect the link element - http://www.thomascsherman.com/downloads/Untitled.png

Comment: @mrtsherman +1 on selecting an element and then looking for event listeners. that's a useful trick. for others in the future, the image he posted is also here (in case of broken links) - http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2390/22902015.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
jQuery('.preview.button').click(function(e){
    window.location.href = this.href;
    return false;
});
```

Works from the Chrome Inspector.

Comment: Works for me too. Nice one Kennis

Comment: Thank you. This is an interesting solution, seems like a bit of a hack, but it does work and it does answer the question that I posted. Somehow though I am still very interested in knowing why the standard methods don't work, and how to find delegated event listeners.

Comment: Just tried with a different version of Google Chrome and it appears that `jQuery('.preview.button').unbind().removeAttr('target')` now works...

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is right but the timing is important. If you just do the first part but not the second part it is possible that this will not work because it seems there is a delay with the event that binds to this element.

If you include the second part as well, that waits for 500ms after the page is loaded to run, it seems that it works as expected.

```
add_action('admin_footer','preview_same_window');

function preview_same_window(){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($){

      //first part
      jQuery('.preview.button').unbind().removeAttr('target');

      //second part
      setTimeout(function(){
       jQuery('.preview.button').unbind().removeAttr('target');
      },500);


    });

    </script>
    <?php
}
```